# gdb how to break or step on forked processes of stripped binaries

Tags: debugging, gdb, reverse-engineering

I have a stripped binary which crashes and I want to reverse it. I tried the 'info file' to get the EntryPoint and set a breakpoint there. However a segmentation fault happens on one of the child processes...

```
 [New process 40472]
 process 40472 is executing new program: /usr/bin/dpkg
 [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
 Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
 [Inferior 2 (process 40472) exited normally]
 E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
 E: Sub-process http received a segmentation fault.
```

From the documentation I found the 'show inferior' but I cant find out how to see the specifics of the segfault ? I tried the 'set follow-fork-mode' to chile but it doesnt look like it is helping. 
For example I would like to examine the values of the registers such as RIP etc.

Stracing the process produces this:

```
 [pid 54137] writev(3, [{"\0\37", 2}, {"{\346\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\4http\4example\3org\0\0\1\0\1", 31}, {"\0\37", 2}, {"\357\24\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\4http\4example\3org\0\0\34\0\1", 31}], 4) = 66
 [pid 54137] read(3,  <unfinished ...>
 [pid 54134] <... read resumed> "\10\376", 2) = 2
 [pid 54134] read(3, "X\250AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"..., 2302) = 2302
 [pid 54134] close(3)                    = 0
 [pid 54134] --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=0} ---
 [pid 54134] +++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
 [pid 54131] <... select resumed> )      = 1 (in [5], left {0, 425835})
 [pid 54131] --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_KILLED, si_pid=54134,  si_uid=0, si_status=SIGSEGV, si_utime=0, si_stime=1} ---
 close(4)
 ....  
 ....
 ....
 close(5)                                = 0
 close(4)                                = 0
 write(2, "E", 1E)                        = 1
 write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
 write(2, "Method http has died unexpectedl"..., 34Method http has died      unexpectedly!) = 34
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
write(2, "E", 1E)                        = 1
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "Sub-process http received a segm"..., 47Sub-process http received a      segmentation fault.) = 47
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(100)                         = ?
+++ exited with 100 +++
```

Comment: When follow-fork-mode is child, when the parent forks, gdb will debug the child and let the parent run unimpeded. If the parent then forks again, gdb may still be attached to the first child and won't notice the new child. That may be what's happening here. Try running `strace -f` on the command and see what the tree of processes looks like.

Comment: thanks Mark, i also added the output on my original post... Does this mean that the child process segfaults and the parental continues running ? is there a way to see the instruction pointer of the child process so that i know that there is an overflow or not happening? I am having troubles with this stripped binary :(

Comment: Yes, that's what's happening. Most Linux systems will log segfaults, so try running `dmesg` and look for a line like `procname[54134] segfault at 0 ip 00000000004004c6`.